# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^n e^{2\pi i (k-1)(a-b)/n}=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

I am trying to show that $$\sum_{k=1}^n e^{2\pi i (k-1)(a-b)/n} = 0$$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive, non-zero integers that run from $1$ to $n$ and $a\neq b$. This is a small part of a larger problem for a linear algebra course and have forgotten much of my complex number theory. I know this should equal zero, after plugging it into a calculator but do not know why exactly.

Could I have any help?

Thanks

Comment: This is a sum of a geometric progression. Note that this is false if $a=b$.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! I forgot to mention that $a\neq b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case $1$: If $a \neq b + mn$, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \big( e^{2\pi i (a-b)/n} \big) ^{k-1}= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \big( e^{2\pi i (a-b)/n} \big) ^{k} =  \frac{1 - e^{2\pi i (a-b)}}{1 - e^{2\pi i (a-b)/n}}$$
then $e^{2\pi i (a-b)} = e^{2 \pi K i} = 1$, where $K \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Case $2$: If $a =b + mn$, where $m \in \mathbb{Z}$**
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \big( e^{2\pi i (a-b)/n} \big) ^{k-1}= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \big( e^{2\pi i (mn)/n} \big) ^{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \big( e^{2\pi i m} \big) ^{k}  = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \big( 1 \big) ^{k} =n$$